# Problem Updating Software to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, updates

In Ubuntu 16.04, trying to update software.  Getting error message `Failed to Download Repository Information`.  My internet connection is OK.  Changed the server twice and still get the same message.  Here is a copy of the detail from the message:

```
W:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jfi/psensor-unstable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file., 
W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jfi/psensor-unstable/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found, 
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xenial repository does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/xenial-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Answer (score 0):

According to [the psensor-unstable PPA on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~jfi/+archive/ubuntu/psensor-unstable), this PPA is not offered for Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial. It only offers packages for up to Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic.

It looks like you tried to integrate the Xenial section of the PPA, which (see above) does not exist. If the repository isn't there, obviously the structures a repository needs to have are not there, in this case the `Releases` and `Packages` files. `apt` basically complains that it couldn't get those two files. And because those two files list what's in the repository, `apt` additionally informs you that for one repository (namely, the psensor-unstable PPA) it was unable to update the list of packages.

If you need some packages from this PPA, you have to look somewhere else for them. If you don't need this PPA any longer, you should be able to savely remove it.