# What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa

When updating, I get the following error message:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Here, I find another statement on this error: [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

This recommends removing certain PPAs; and, I'm not sure if I should do that since it might mean not getting the updates that I need.

Is this what I should do?

Comment: xenial is probably no longer supported should upgrade. You should change all repositories to use old-release.ubuntu.com instead, and then do `sudo do-releases-upgrade` to get an supported release of Ubuntu.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
Oh, it was an old PPA.  I just had this problem myself, and it was solved by this trick.  I came here first when I did a search.

Comment: Before you try anything else make sure you have network access from your server to the internet. Otherwise you will get this error too.

Comment: @Anders as of this date Xenial is still supported with maintenance updates. When in doubt you can check [the release schedule](https://www.ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The PPA you've added does not support your version of Ubuntu, meaning there aren't any packages for your particular release.

For example, the `ppa:mc3man/trusty-media` PPA is only for Trusty (Ubuntu 14.04) only (trusty-media). Obviously, it has no files for Xenial (16.04). You can check the [PPA's Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/%7Emc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media) to see which versions of Ubuntu are supported.

I'd suggest the following:

- Remove the PPA for an older release. For this example:
  `sudo ppa-purge ppa:mc3man/trusty-media`

- If there's a PPA for your curent release, add it. In this case, there's a PPA for Xenial: [mc3man/xerus-media](https://launchpad.net/%7Emc3man/+archive/ubuntu/xerus-media). You can add it using
  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/xerus-media`

To summarize, you need to remove the added PPA, and use another one that has packages for your particular release.

Comment: So first thing:  I didn't have `ppa-purge` so as a note if anyone in the future reads this answer:  You may first need to get it by running `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`.

Comment: Second, I tried the first bullet point and I got the warning `Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason` after some other error messages that usually come with `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Also after doing the second bullet point and then running `sudo apt-get update` I get the usual error messages.  I'm guessing at this point I should disable the associated Trust Media thing.

Comment: Yep, after un-checking some check boxes for Trusty Media and mc3man under System Settings > Software and Updates > Other software, then I ran update again and get no error messages.  I have about 90% confidence I didn't remove anything that I need.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.

Comment: If you don't have `ppa-purge` just use `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:…` instead.

Comment: @dessert that is the simplest way, as there are no packages installed from the PPA.

Comment: i don't understand why it "doesn't support your version of Ubuntu"... when I first added the PPA it had no problems installing, and I haven't upgraded, so why is it suddenly broken like this???

Comment: @Michael maybe the maintainer removed support for the release afterwards; see the PPA webpage.

Comment: See [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1302382/21005) for an exception to this rule and for an improved version of *ppa-purge*.

Comment: This answer doesn't work, rather use the answer below that is about `System Settings > Software and Updates > Other Software`

Answer (score 85):

Remove the PPA with the line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
```

Now run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue, this method worked for me.

Comment: My repository was named `'http://ppa.launchpad.net/network-manager/trunk/ubuntu focal Release'` so I had to `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:network-manager/trunk` instead.

Comment: THis worked for me on POpOS20.04. Thanks!

Comment: worked for me as well I removed some python error repo

Answer (score 45):

Yes, unchecking some tick boxes for **Trusty Media** and **mc3man** under

**System Settings** > **Software and Updates** > **Other Software**

did the trick. `ppa-purge` didn't work for me.

Comment: What to do if this is used on a server?

Comment: An advantage of this is [being able to re-enable the PPA](https://askubuntu.com/q/111645/419483) if you just want to disable it temporarily, rather than simply purging the whole thing.

Answer (score 24):

From my personal experience I can recommend to directly contact the PPA owner (if we talk about PPA) to kindly ask him/her to prepare packages for needed (usually newer, so supported release) with steps below:

1. Temporarily disable the PPA in your system (see other answer).
2. Visit PPA page on https://launchpad.net and login to it.
3. Determine the uploader's name in **Uploaded by** column, click on the name's hyperlink
4. Then click on *Contact this user*

   > [image: Contact this user]
5. And fill the form with all necessary information:

   > **From:** *your e-mail will be shown in plain here*
   >   **Subject:** *Packaging of AppName for Ubuntu NN.MM release*
   >   **Message:**
   >
   > Dear PPA owner!
   >
   > Thank you for your work on the *AppName*.
   >   It would be great if you create the package for it for Ubuntu *NN.MM* release.
   >
   > With best regards,
   >   *user*.
6. Wait for an e-mail from PPA owner.
7. Add PPA again to the system when package get published.
8. Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

In some cases a package meant for an older release of Ubuntu works in a newer release, too. This is currently the case with my [ppa-purge PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejarnos/+archive/ubuntu/ppa-purge); see the website for instructions. Note that the official *ppa-purge* has had the same version 0.2.8+bzr63 since Ubuntu Xenial (16.04).